# Converting List<String> to List<Map<String,dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert my **List** to **List<Map<String,dynamic>>**? The `selected` field value will always be false.

```
List<String> stringList = ["one", "two", "three"];

List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [
 {"name": "one","selected": false},
 {"name": "two","selected": false},
 {"name": "three", "selected": false}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = stringList.map(
    (s) => {'name': s, 'selected': false}
).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need something like this?

```
List<String> stringList = ["one", "two", "three"];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [];

stringList.forEach((element) {
  mapList.add({"name": "$element", "selected": false});
});
```

It will loop the **stringList** array and take each element and put it in the **mapList**

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

```
void main() {
  List<String> stringList = ["one", "two", "three"];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [];

  stringList.forEach((e) {
    Map<String, dynamic> item = {"name": e, "selected": false};
    mapList.add(item);
  });

  print(mapList);
}
```

output:

```
[
{name: one, selected: false}, 
{name: two, selected: false}, 
{name: three, selected: false}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
List<String> stringList = ["one", "two", "three"];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [];

for (var element in stringList) {
mapList.add({"name": element, "selected": false});}

print(mapList);
}
```

output

```
[{name: one, selected: false}, 
{name: two, selected: false}, 
{name: three, selected: false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but I believe the most idiomatic solution would be to use [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists). Effective dart recommends [DO use collection literals when possible](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-collection-literals-when-possible).

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [
  for (final element in stringList) 
    {"name": element, "selected": false},
];
```